# Multi country site in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a site in my Hybris project having a URL pattern like:

`localhost:9002/en-uk`

Where the storefront context root was also kept as en-uk in mystorefront **project.properties** file.

How do I extend this for other countries and create a new site for my new country.I tried changing the existing site impex and changing the URL there but it did not yield anything.

Should I change the storefront context root in mystorefront **project.properties** file as highlighted above?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single storefront extension then your storefront context is common for all sites (CMSSite). I would suggest to keep it as root (/). If you really want to have a storefront context in the site URL then keep it generic. Do not include countries/language code as it doesn't make sense when someone accesses the US site with /en-uk.

---

### 1) Set storefront context to root

1. Change HAC webroot from `/` to `/hac`
2. Set your storefront webroot & StorfrontContextRoot to blank
3. Change website & media URL for each cmsStore
4. Make host file entry for  `127.0.0.1 localhost us.local uk.local`

In **local.properties**

```
hac.webroot=/hac

#change <yourproject> with your storefront extension prefix
<yourproject>storefront.webroot=

#If you are using B2C then below propery would be StorefrontContextRoot
b2bStorefrontContextRoot=

#change usCMSSiteUI with your us CMS site uid and similar for UK
website.usCMSSiteUID.http=http://us.local:9001
website.usCMSSiteUID.https=https://us.local:9002
media.usCMSSiteUID.http=http://us.local:9001
media.usCMSSiteUID.https=https://us.local:9002

website.ukCMSSiteUID.http=http://uk.local:9001
website.ukCMSSiteUID.https=https://uk.local:9002
media.ukCMSSiteUID.http=http://uk.local:9001
media.ukCMSSiteUID.https=https://uk.local:9002
```

---

### 2) Configure each CMSSite with the unique URL pattern

Hope you already have CMSSite instance for each site. For each site, you have to configure the URL pattern.

e.g. 
[image]

**UK CMSsite**

```
(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=UK)(|\&.*)$
(?i)^https?://uk\.local:9002$
```

**US CMSsite**

```
(?i)^https?://[^/]+(/[^?]*)?\?(.*\&)?(site=US)(|\&.*)$
(?i)^https?://us\.local:9002$
```

---

### 3) Start your server and access it

If you have configured your sites correctly as I mentioned above, then you can access it like

https://us.local:9002
https://uk.local:9002

For production setup, you can configure (sub-)domains for each site URL patter or take help of web server to resolve requests by passing **?site=us** or **uk**.