# Creating Multiple storefronts in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

### Hybris Version used: **6.5**

**Current Scenario**
We have an implementation that has the following implemented

1. SAP to Hybris connector (datahub) (manage customers, products, prices, stock levels)
2. One storefront ( product, carts)
3. Integration with payment system

Everything works fine .

### **The questions:**

1. Ability to create multiple new storefronts (apart from the main one) on the fly => event based storefronts that stay online for a pre-defined period and then shut down(based on some rule/trigger)
2. Reuse the SAP to Hybris connector from above(to manage products, prices, stock levels etc).
3. Reuse the integration with payment system from above.
4. The main storefront operates as usual

Is this functionality supported in Hybris? If yes, how is it achieved? What needs to be done? Any suggestions?

Comment: I reformatted your question so that the layout can be more easily read. Also, I removed the "thanks" and signature, which are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple CMSSite without development, details are in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059250/multi-country-site-in-hybris).
If there are static context/url exist in design or code, you need to make changes on code. For example payment callback url.
If you plan to split products by site, maybe you need changes on datahub for using separate product catalog.

Comment: Thanks, Will go through the answer you provided and try and see if this helps my purpose.

Comment: @mkysoft : Multiple `storefronts` can be used to apply different business logics in controllers. Creating multiple CMSSite would not offer the flexibility to apply different logic. All the CMSSite will use the same business logic defined in that one `controller`.

Answer (score 1):

## Possible solutions-

1. #### *New storefronts*-

   You can create multiple storefronts in a project just the same way you [create a new extension](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8b96270b86691014b1c3bbfd7556f0ed.html) using `extegen`. Select default template as `yacceleratorstorefront`. If multiple controller methods have same URL and type (GET, POST, etc.) then add the annotation `@RequestMappingOverride` on top of the method in your ***main*** storefront. You need to do this ONLY if you want to implement different business logic for same URL and type. To shutdown a `storefront` you have to remove the `storefront` entry from `localextensions.xml` and run the build before starting server. There is **no** way to do this *on the fly*.
2. #### *Reuse the SAP to Hybris connector*-

   Product, prices and stock levels are saved in the databse. These values can be used by different `CMSSite` and different `storefronts` **without** any extra customization.
3. #### *Reuse payment integration system*-

   A popular way of doing this is [creating a dedicated *addon*](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8acd154b866910148da4ba58bdd6dc86.html) for each payment type using a common *payment addon* template. *Eg*- `cybersourcepaymentaddon`, `paypaladdon`, etc.

Each storefront will operate *independently*.